# Dynamic GraphQL schema?

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have a mutation that is going to submit a form data, this data can vary depending by the form you are filling out.

The forms are going to be a lot, and they will share the same "steps" (each form is composed by 1 or more pages/steps).

So, we may have these reusable steps:

- Fav fruit
- Date of birth
- Name and surname

And these two forms:

- Generic info (`genericInfo`): Name and surname + Date of birth
- What do you eat? (`whatYouEat`): Name and surname + Fav fruit

I'd need a way to have a single mutation, that allows to define the form name, and takes a `data` object that needs to be validated based on such form name.

For instance, if I call this mutation:

```
submitForm(formName: $formName, formData: $formData) {
  resultMessage
}
```

with `formName` set to `genericInfo` and `formData` set to `{ nameAndSurname: 'Foo Bar', favFruit: 'apple' }`, it should throw an error because `genericInfo` doesn't expect `favFruit`, but `dateOfBirth`.

Can this be achieved with GraphQL? Are there better ways to get here maybe?

Answer (score 5):

GraphQL doesn’t directly allow this.  Input object types have fixed structure, and there’s no conditional validation (built-in; your resolver function could produce errors based on its own checks that are richer than what’s in the schema).

The most common pattern I’ve seen adopts the [Relay GraphQL mutation conventions](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/graphql-server-specification.html#mutations) (even if you don’t expect your clients to be using Relay).  This has one mutation per possible action (in your case, one mutation per submitted form) and a distinct input object type per mutation.

Also note that the input object types can be nested, so in your example, you could write

```
input Name {
  givenName: String!
  surname: String!
}

input Fruit {
  name: String!
}

input WhatYouEatInput {
  name: Name!
  fruit: Fruit!
}

mutation {
  whatYouEat(input: WhatYouEatInput!): WhatYouEatPayload!
}
```

which would allow reusing the common parts of the schema across different mutation types.

Comment: Thanks, that's the current implementation I'm using... But it doesn't scale if I'm going to have 100 forms :-(

Answer (score 2):

It would be possible to do this if GraphQL provided a Union type that could be used as input. This [has been suggested before](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/207), but there seems to be no plans to implement it in the near future.

So, since you will have dozens of possible combinations on the form data, I think your best option would be to just send a string in JSON format with the data, and do the validation yourself, using some structure that defines all possible `formName` and its allowed fields.

But this way you would not be taking advantage of GraphQL typing system.

Comment: Even if we use JSON type for storing. It's so difficult to filter the data.