# Is it possible to send data of dynamic types to GraphQL, or to modify an existing schema?

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js, keystonejs

I'm using KeystoneJS' custom fields to build a dropdown that is populated from data in the API.  Building the custom field works fine, but when I try to save the data to the server (that is, when I let KeystoneJS save the data to the server through its GraphQL API), I get

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$data" got invalid value "another" at "data.sploof"; Expected type TodoSploofType., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined
```

I'm fairly new to GraphQL, but I believe the issue is that the data I'm passing, `another` in field `sploof`, is not in the schema.
[image]

Instead, it has `pending` and `processed`,  which come from when I set up KeystoneJS -- here you see the field `sploof` has the custom type `MySelect` with the `schemaDoc` containing `options`:

```
keystone.createList('Todo', {
    schemaDoc: 'A list of things which need to be done',
    fields: {
        name: {type: Text, schemaDoc: 'This is the thing you need to do'},
        blip: {type: Text, schemaDoc: 'This is another thing'},
        status: {type: Select, options: 'pending, processed'},
        sploof: {type: MySelect, options: 'pending, processed'},

    },
});
```

In general, is there a way to modify GraphQL schemas once they've been created?  That is, if I want to send data whose shape will be determined at run-time?

Comment: I dont think, sending Graphql schemas as dynamic is possible.(maybe you can send json and make the schema as String) Kindly check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251065/dynamic-graphql-schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keystone Select is of defined type, you can not send a dynamic value for this.

if you want to have new item added to the field you can create a RelationShip type field and add new item randomly but that may not work well all the time due to storing only mongo id of ref objedct.

I see that you are writing a custom field, if you can have your custom field load data from the the list and let user select (base type is still Text) so you can then use the dynamic option there. You can also create a custom field to list values for the field from same list. kind of typeahead based on existing values

it may take time for me to create a working code.

Comment: In the end I went with a pure Relationship field which works great -- that is, if I want to relate one 'Article' with other Articles, that is, translations of that Article, then I just have a Relationship field in the Article list (`translations: {type: Relationship, ref: 'Article', many: true}`).  I'm unclear what you meant by "but that may not work well all the time due to storing only mongo id of ref objedct".  It seems like this should work fine, after all, that's the point of Relationship fields, no?  Is there any reason why what I'm doing wouldn't work?

Comment: you are doing right, I had something form my customer that they did not want to store relationship id field, it is extended select field where value come from a different list and there is no relation.